# How to unsubscribe logs / events?

Tags: solidity, events, logs

There are two ways to subscribe/watch to logs/events:

**Subscribe:**

```
var subscription = web3.eth.subscribe('logs', {
    address: '0x123456..',
    topics: ['0x12345...']
}, function(error, result){
    if (!error)
        console.log(log);
});
```

**Unsubscribe:**

```
subscription.unsubscribe(function(error, success){
    if(success)
        console.log('Successfully unsubscribed!');
});
```

But how do I unsubscribe if I watch the logs / events like this:

```
myContractWebsocket.events.MyLogName({
    filter: {'orderId': '0x123456...'}, 
    fromBlock: 0
    })
    .on('data', data => { console.log(data); })
    .on('error', error => { console.log(error); });
```

Answer (score 1):

Struggled with this as well, here is my solution:

**Event Setup**

```js
let subscriptionId;
const eventEmitter = web3.contract.events.MyEvent({...options})
   .on('connected', id => subscriptionId = id)
   .on('data', event => {
      // Your event logic
    })
```

**Unsubscribe**

```js
// Unsubscribe if connected successfully and not undefined
if(!subscriptionId) return
eventEmitter.options.requestManager.removeSubscription(subscriptionId)
```

Answer (score 0):

`myContractWebsocket.events.MyLogName` returns a `Subscription` response, which has an unsubscribe method. See [here](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/1587) for a bit more detail.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work like that. I get TypeError: subscription.unsubscribe is not a function

Comment: @RobMagier could you add the code from attempting this answer, along with the error, into the question?